# I am trying to like a comment in instagram with selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots, instagram

My code is this:

```
comments_to_like = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_8-yf5 ')
time.sleep(5)

n += 1
x = 0
for each in range(len(comments_to_like)):
    liked = random.choice(comments_to_like)
    time.sleep(5)

    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(comments_to_like[each]).click(comments_to_like[each]).perform()
```

I was trying with action chain but not sure if this can help.

here is the dom of Instagram

```
<div class="QBdPU ">
    <span class="">
        <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="12" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="12">
            <path d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2-11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path>
        </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to like the comments not sure how to do it any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's a good idea to select by class in this scenario, because the class name looks like a random generated name.

In line:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(comments_to_like[each]).click(comments_to_like[each]).perform()
```

You should do ( but i am not 100% sure that it works ) :

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(comments_to_like[each]).click().perform()
```

Or you could rewrite it something like this:

```
all_svg=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("svg")

for svg in all_svg:
    if svg.get_attribute("aria-label") == "Like":
        svg.click()
```

Comment: Thank you this work but now I am have MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException from selenium any suggestion Its have some pattern code to handle this exception.

Comment: I am using Firefox webdriver

Comment: @MikeHadzhiev .move_to_element() fails and raises the MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException, try to click it in other way, you could try:`comments_to_like[each].click()` instead of `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(comments_to_like[each]).click().perform()`